# how can i extract features from a document

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science, feature-extraction, document-classification

i have a document for which i want to extract features which are important .on that the selection should be such that each category has different columns or (descriptions).suppose if a category has 5 different selections . how will i know which is the important one ??

How can i select the features based upon some specific rules so that when any other document is fed into the model ,it should pick the most important categories and their selections even if same category might have different selections as well?

Comment: Could you be more specific? Give examples, show what you have attempted with code and what data you have. This is how you get answers in Stack Overflow. =)

Comment: problem is split into 2 parts 1)how do i extract specific heading names from  various documents(.docx files).    2) if that  heading is present in the documents when any documents are parsed ..it should pick up that heading and respective tables

Comment: TiagoDuque as i am very new to python coding and in the field of nlp i tried out below from docx import Document

file = 'test.docx'
document = Document(file)

for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    if paragraph.style.name == 'my header ':
        print(paragraph.text)     but this gave out nothing but empty string .   how can i interate over the document pages for a specific header is the scenario

Comment: Please, add that to the question with correct formating. You can find all help in doing that here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example